# C# equivalent for bool operator and rhs in c++

Tags: c#, c++, boolean, operator-keyword

I'm trying to convert a C++ code to C# and this part of my code is a little bit confusing. I'm wondering if someone helps me to understand what it does and perhaps what is its equivalent in c#.

```
struct Solution
{
    std::vector<double> y;
    bool operator<(const Solution& rhs) const
    {
        if (y < rhs.y)
            return true;
        return false;
    };
}
```

Comment: That's operator overloading FYI...

Answer (score 1):

The code overloads the `<` operator, to allow a comparison of two `Solution` objects by their `y` value.

After overloading the operator this way

```
solution1 < solution2
```

has the same meaning as

```
solution1.y < solution2.y
```

You can do this in C#, too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/operator

I don't know much C++, I think the equivalent of a `vector<double>` in C# should be a `List<double>` (System.Collections.Generic.List). I'm not sure, how C++ compares two `vector<double>`, so let's just pretend, `y` in your example is just a double. This would result in this C# code:

```
struct Solution
{
    private double y;

    public static bool operator <(Solution a, Solution b)
    {
        return a.y < b.y;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Solution a, Solution b)
    {
        return a.y > b.y;
    }
}
```

(Because in you can't define a `<` operator without a matching `>` operator)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should i define the overloading or program create it?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand your question. I hope the edit of my answer helps.